# Restore GRUB splash screen

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, kde

I have installed Fedora 26 KDE along with Windows 10. Today I forgetfully checked no splash screen and restarted. Now I can not login to Fedora. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/655279/124500) from windows but no luck.

Comment: The solution to which you link is fixing Windows 10 overwriting the Linux boot configuration, whereas your problem is that the Linux boot configuration is misconfigured. Your best bet is to boot into a live Linux distribution (if you have Fedora boot media, this may work), and modify the grub.cfg file, likely somewhere in the /boot directory on disk. Good luck!

Comment: Where did you check "no splash screen"?

Comment: @mattdm from system settings. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/xGhhBuc.gif

Comment: Is that in Windows?

Comment: @mattdm no Fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the boot menu. There I found the Fedora KDE entry along with Windows 10. I just logged in and unchecked no splash screen and restarted.